# ICS emulator not loading

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to run the Android emulator with the ICS (Android 4.0) OS but after a 15 minute wait on a fast quad core machine, it's still not doing anything.  I understand it's emulating the arm cpu, hence it's slow - but this hasn't even gotten off the loading screen yet!  Has anyone managed to get it to run?  Any tips?

Comment: Try launching without the `Launch from snapshot`

Comment: Its already working fine here. Just loaded as other SDK without any problem

Comment: @DanielFekete That's the correct answer - running without 'launch from snapshot' seems to work - write it up with a bit more padding to get around the small length restriction and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try launching without the `Launch from snapshot` feature

Launching some of my AVD's from command line with

```
./emulator -avd ...
```

Gives

```
savevm: unable to load section cpu
```

that may or may not be related to the problem(?), but basically launching without the snapshot starts up the emulator.

This happened after I upgraded to Android SDK to 4.0

Comment: but what happen or what is the snapshot feature ?? please answer

Answer (score 1):

My solution is the starting Emulator manually but with Target 2.2., let's say with API level 8, then your project will be easily loaded on Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I made sure to turn off "Load from Snapshot". And mine will still not load. I am going on about an 1 hour now and still sitting

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I succeeded to get ICS emulator by executing `$ emulator-arm -avd your_avd_name` whereas launching from eclipse (i.e. going through `emulator.exe` instead of `emulator-arm.exe`) fails consistently.